# Undoing changes two commits and getting to clean state.

Tags: git

Say I have a commit history that looks like this:

`A <- B <- C`

I am currently on C. I hate both my commits B and C and I want to get back to A with a clean staging and no changes.. I want the state of A. How do I do this in the most efficient way. I am currently doing this:

```
git revert --no-commit B
git revert --no-commit A
git checkout .
```

This also makes it so there is no revert commit/no new commit showing my revert. Say I want this. What do I do?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: `git reset —hard A`?

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard A
```

That will take you back to revision A and it's very close to saying "b and C didn't happen". Also, the current branch will start pointing to A so, use with care.

If what you want is a new revision D that follows C (A <- B <- C <- D) so that it has the same content as A, then you could try this:

```
git checkout A -- . # take back content of the whole project to how A was
git commit -m "Going back to revision A"
```

If you want to do it with reverts that don't create a commit:

```
git revert --no-commit A..C
git commit -m "going back to A"
```

Or:

```
git revert --no-edit A..C
git reset --soft HEAD~2 # Moving branch pointer to C keeping everything else as-is
git commit -m "going back to A"
```

Comment: then likely a `git push -f`

Comment: I want to keep the branch continuing with revert, no reset--hard. How do I do this?

Comment: @Jwan622 Adjusted recipe.

Comment: How do I do this with reverts?

Answer (score 0):

to go back to commit A, follow below command:

```
git reset --hard A
```

and if you still have some untracked files on your local, you can run below command:

```
git clean -f -d
```

But if your branch is also used by other people, then the best solution would be to use revert command only to avoid conflicts for everyone.

Comment: I want to keep the branch continuing with revert, no reset--hard. How do I do this?

Comment: @Jwan622 Can you be more elaborative about what exactly you want?

Comment: I don't want to use reset --hard because that doesn't create a new commit